# Page shift fix has odd consequence

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

I am creating a simple module that expands when you click a button to reveal more content. I was having an issue with the page shifting after expanding the content field so I set the overflow to scroll on the body and that fixed the issue. What's now happening though is when I reduce the screen size to below 768px the vertical and horizontal scrollbars around the container for these modules show up and on expand a new vertical scrollbar shows up and causes the shift to happen.

There are some bootstrap styles involved here so I'm not sure if I should post that code, comment if it would help and I'll add it to the question.

Here's a little code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container"> 
  <!-- container div in place to restrict width to more closely resemble cms template -->
  <div class="row spec-header">
    <figure class="col-sm-4 col-wm-4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x300" class="img-responsive">
    </figure>
    <h1 class="col-sm-4 col-wm-4">11050</h1>
    <button class="text-info spec-toggle">Specifications <span class="icon-down  icon-inverse-circle">&#8203;</span></button>
  </div>
  <div class="row specs">
    <ul class="col-sm-4 col-wm-4 list-unstyled">
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Intelligent Traffic Processing:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li><strong>L7 requests per second:</strong> 2.5M</li>
          <li><strong>L4 connections per second:</strong> 1M</li>
          <li><strong>Maximum L4 concurrent connections:</strong> 24M</li>
          <li><strong>Throughput:</strong> 42 Gbps/40 Gbps L4/L7</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Hardware SSL:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li><strong>Included:</strong> 500 TPS</li>
          <li><strong>Maximum:</strong> 20,000 TPS (2K keys)</li>
          <li>15 Gbps bulk encryption<sup><a href="#fn-2">*</a></sup></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>FIPS SSL:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>FIPS 140-2 Level 2 (option)</li>
          <li>9,000 TPS (2K keys)</li>
          <li>15 Gbps bulk encryption<sup><a href="#fn-2">*</a></sup></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Hardware DDoS Protection:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>N/A</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Hardware Compression:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>N/A</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Software Compression:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li><strong>Included:</strong> 50 Mbps</li>
          <li><strong>Maximum:</strong> 12 Gbps</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Software Architecture:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>64-bit TMOS</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>On-Demand Upgradable:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>N/A</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Processor:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>Dual CPU, hex core (12 processing cores)</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="col-sm-4 col-wm-4 list-unstyled">
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Memory:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>32 GB</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Hard Drive:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>Two 600 GB drives, 10,000 RPM (RAID 1)</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Gigabit Ethernet CU Ports:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>Optional SFP</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Gigabit Fiber Ports (SFP):</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>Optional SFP (SX or LX)</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>10 Gigabit Fiber Ports (SFP+):</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>10 SR or LR (sold separately, 2 SR included); Optional 10G copper direct attach</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>40 Gigabit Fiber Ports (QSFP+):</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>N/A</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Power Supply:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>Dual 850W included, DC optional</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Typical Consumption:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>440W (dual A/C power - 110V input)</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Input Voltage:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>90–240 VAC +/- 10% auto switching, 50/60 hz</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Typical Heat Output:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>1501 BTU/hour (110V input)</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="col-sm-4 col-wm-4 list-unstyled">
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Dimensions:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>5.2” (13.2 cm) H x 17.4” (44.2 cm) W x 21.4” (54.36 cm) D3U industry standard rack-mount chassis</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Weight:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>52 lbs. (23.6 kg) (dual power supply)</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Operating Temperature:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>32° to 104° F (0° to 40° C)</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Operational Relative Humidity:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>5 to 85% at 40° C</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Safety Agency Approval:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>UL 60950-1:2001, 1st Edition</li>
          <li>CSA C22.2 No. 60950-1-03</li>
          <li>IEC 60950-1: 2005, 2nd Edition</li>
          <li>EN 60950-1: 2005, 2nd Edition</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><p class="text-info"><strong>Certifications/Susceptibility Standards:</strong></p>
        <ul class="text-muted list-unstyled">
          <li>EN 55022:2006 + C1:2006</li>
          <li>EN 55024:1998 + A1: 2001 + A2:2003</li>
          <li>FCC Part 15B Class A</li>
          <li>VCCI Class A</li>
          <li>NEBS compliant (option)</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  max-width: 850px;
}

body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
/* Spec header region*/
.spec-header {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-top: 8px solid rgba(196, 195, 194, 0.85);
  position: relative;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(209,214,213,0.44) 0%, rgba(169,200,222,0.16) 36%, rgba(136,189,229,0) 65%, rgba(125,185,232,0) 75%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(209,214,213,0.44)), color-stop(36%,rgba(169,200,222,0.16)), color-stop(65%,rgba(136,189,229,0)), color-stop(75%,rgba(125,185,232,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(209,214,213,0.44) 0%,rgba(169,200,222,0.16) 36%,rgba(136,189,229,0) 65%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 75%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(209,214,213,0.44) 0%,rgba(169,200,222,0.16) 36%,rgba(136,189,229,0) 65%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 75%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(209,214,213,0.44) 0%,rgba(169,200,222,0.16) 36%,rgba(136,189,229,0) 65%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 75%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(209,214,213,0.44) 0%,rgba(169,200,222,0.16) 36%,rgba(136,189,229,0) 65%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 75%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#70d1d6d5', endColorstr='#007db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


  button {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    min-width: 140px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  h1 {
    margin: 0;
  }
}


/*Spec list region*/

.list-unstyled ul {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.specs {
  height: 1px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.active {
  height: 920px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

/*Media queries*/

@media (max-width: 768px) {

  .spec-header {
    text-align: center;
    button {
      position: static;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }

  .specs {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

And some jquery, though I don't know how this could be causing it:

```
$('.spec-toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next(".specs").toggleClass("active");    
  });
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this!